# Chart for Benchmark data isn't calculated properly

Tags: sql-server, r, charts, ggplot2

I posed this question a few days ago but it has diverged in the comments enough that I think it's worthy of asking many of the points in the comments in a new question. I apologize for the length of this question. I hope that it isn't terribly unclear.

I'm working on creating a chart using ggplot2 in a R Sweave file used to track benchmarks for software. I'm looking specifically at run times for the benchmark and either want to use % Deviation or deviation by minutes from the *earliest* test run that we have data for. The reason I say earliest and not the first is because in earlier versions of the software, we had frequent crashes which led to specific test runs not having data for a particular file.

This is the R code I'm currently trying to build the chart with:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table) #package I'm using to create the benchmark data

dbhandle <- SQLConn_remote(DBName = "DATABASE", ServerName = "SERVER")
Testdf<-sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from TABLENAME order by FileName, Number, Category', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

versions<-unique(Testdf[order(Testdf$Number), ][,2])

#using data.table package
setDT(Testdf)
Testdf[, Benchmark := Value[which.min(Number)], by = "FileName"]

Testdf$Version<-factor(Testdf$Version, levels = versions)
Testdf$Deviation<-Testdf$Value- Testdf$Benchmark
Testdf$DeviationP<-(Testdf$Value- Testdf$Benchmark)/Testdf$Benchmark

g<-ggplot(subset(Testdf, Category == 'Time' & !is.na(Value) & Deviation <.5) , aes(color = Value, x = Version, y = Deviation, group = FileName)) + 
  geom_line(size=.25) + geom_point(aes(shape = Build), size = 1.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,15)) + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="line") + 
  ylab("Run Time Deviation from Benchmark (min)") +  
  scale_colour_gradient(name = 'Run Time (min)',low = 'blue', high = 'red') + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90, vjust = .5)) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.1)) + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"mm"))
g
```

(*If you'd like to recreate this, see the example data frame at the bottom*)

This is an example of what the SQL Table looks like:

[image: Testdf - An Example Table]

And this is what the chart looks like when generated using the actual SQL data:

[image: Bad Benchmark Chart]

The main problem is that every single line should begin at zero. It shouldn't begin at the virst x-axis tick point because like I said above, sometimes errors cause the program to crash during a run leaving no data. So the benchark should be calculated from the *earliest* available run or what ever `Number`is min for that particular `FileName`. Each line should represent the `Category` of `Time` for a specific `FileName` and the chart is `Value` vs `Version`.

The headache for me is why this isn't working. I need the benchmark to be chosen by the minimum `Number` entry for a specific `FileName` and chart its `Time`.

#### EDIT: I realized that using data.table is going to cause problems further down in the code so doing this without that package would be preferable.

#### 2nd EDIT:

Here's what the benchmark data needs to be (and I'm having code block). I need to select the minimum `Number` entry for each unique `FileName`. Once that's done, I need there to be a new column on Testdf called Benchmark that is the `Value` of the Time `Category` for each unique `FileName` at the minimum `Number`.

---

Here's an quick example data frame I created for you to use in recreating the SQL Table:

```
rw1 <- c("File1", "File1", "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File3", "File3", "File3", "File1", "File1", "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File3", "File3", "File3", "File1", "File1", "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File3", "File3", "File3")
rw2 <- c("0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03")
rw3 <- c("Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final")
rw4 <- c(123, 456, 789, 312, 645, 978, 741, 852, 963, 369, 258, 147, 753, 498, 951, 753, 915, 438, 978, 741, 852, 963, 369, 258, 147, 753, 498)
rw5 <- c("01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12")
rw6 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
rw7 <- c("Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release")
rw8 <- c("None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "Cannot Connect to Database", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None")


Testdf = data.frame(rw1, rw2, rw3, rw4, rw5, rw6, rw7, rw8)
colnames(Testdf) <- c("FileName", "Version", "Category", "Value", "Date", "Number", "Build", "Error")
```

Comment: Maybe you can just `dput` the data you are plotting (or a sample of it) and get rid of the data.table and sql tags on this question (which seem to have nothing to do with your core ggplot2 problem).

Comment: @Frank I can't provide any of the actual data.

Comment: I just noticed you have an example at the bottom. That works. A lot of the code you're providing at the top seems extraneous to the problem, but I'll leave it to experts on ggplot2 (which I never use).

Comment: @Frank the only code I could think that is extraneous would be the versions variable that is used in labeling the x-axis but you're right it isn't specifically related to the problem at hand but I included it so that the entire chart is built as is.

Comment: also, if you are having issues using data.table, just put a line `Test.df <- data.frame(Testdf)` before the place where you are experiencing issues (or find the root cause of the issue)