# Selecting a unique value from an R data frame

Tags: r

If I have a table like this:

```
| FileName | Category| Value | Number |
|:--------:|:-------:|:-----:|:------:|
| File1    | Time    | 123   | 1      |
| File1    | Size    | 456   | 1      |
| File1    | Final   | 789   | 1      |
| File2    | Time    | 312   | 2      |
| File2    | Size    | 645   | 2      |
| File2    | Final   | 978   | 2      |
| File3    | Time    | 741   | 1      |
| File3    | Size    | 852   | 1      |
| File3    | Final   | 963   | 1      |
| File1    | Time    | 369   | 2      |
| File1    | Size    | 258   | 2      |
| File1    | Final   | 147   | 2      |
| File3    | Time    | 741   | 2      |
| File3    | Size    | 734   | 2      |
| File3    | Final   | 942   | 2      |
| File1    | Time    | 997   | 3      |
| File1    | Size    | 245   | 3      |
| File1    | Final   | 985   | 3      |
| File2    | Time    | 645   | 3      |
| File2    | Size    | 285   | 3      |
| File2    | Final   | 735   | 3      |
| File3    | Time    | 198   | 3      |
| File3    | Size    | 165   | 3      |
| File3    | Final   | 753   | 3      |
```

What means could I use in an R script to declare a variable that is the `Value` for each `FileName` where `Number` is *minimum* and `Category` is `Time`?

(***EDIT:*** *It should be noted that there are* `null` *entries in the* `Value` *column. Therefore, this code should be constructed to treat null entries as though they didn't exist so* `New Column` *doesn't end up filled with* `NA` *values.*)

Then I'd like to `merge` this to form a new column on the existing table so that it now looks like this:

```
| FileName | Category | Value | Number | New Column |
|:--------:|:--------:|:-----:|:------:|------------|
| File1    | Time     | 123   | 1      | 123        |
| File1    | Size     | 456   | 1      | 123        |
| File1    | Final    | 789   | 1      | 123        |
| File2    | Time     | 312   | 2      | 312        |
| File2    | Size     | 645   | 2      | 312        |
| File2    | Final    | 978   | 2      | 312        |
| File3    | Time     | 741   | 1      | 741        |
| File3    | Size     | 852   | 1      | 741        |
| File3    | Final    | 963   | 1      | 741        |
| File1    | Time     | 369   | 2      | 369        |
| File1    | Size     | 258   | 2      | 369        |
| File1    | Final    | 147   | 2      | 369        |
| File3    | Time     | 741   | 2      | 741        |
| File3    | Size     | 734   | 2      | 741        |
| File3    | Final    | 942   | 2      | 741        |
| File1    | Time     | 997   | 3      | 997        |
| File1    | Size     | 245   | 3      | 997        |
| File1    | Final    | 985   | 3      | 997        |
| File2    | Time     | 645   | 3      | 645        |
| File2    | Size     | 285   | 3      | 645        |
| File2    | Final    | 735   | 3      | 645        |
| File3    | Time     | 198   | 3      | 198        |
| File3    | Size     | 165   | 3      | 198        |
| File3    | Final    | 753   | 3      | 198        |
```

Comment: Read the basic R documentation. Functions like `subset`, `min` and `==` will be of use in approaching this problem.

Comment: @Frank I'm familiar with those. However, I can't seem to get the logic worked out with all of the different conditions.

Comment: `dplyr` , `data.table` packages or `tapply` from baseR.

Comment: @BondedDust: I think OP means category Time of a variable Measure.

Comment: Still scratching my head. So Measure column just gets renamed to Time? Or is there some data to merge to?

Comment: @BondedDust Measure as the column name is something I forgot to fix when I used Category instead. That was simply an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using data.table:

(Edited to reflect @Frank's comments)

`DT[, Benchmark := Value[Category == "Time"][which.min(Number[Category == "Time"])], by = FileName]`

**Breaking this down:**

`Number[Category == "Time"]`

- Take all `Number` where `Category == Time`

`which.min(^^^)`

- Find which one is the minimum

`Benchmark := Value[Category == "Time"][^^^]`

- Set the new column of benchmark to the value at this minimum

`by = FileName`

- Do this by group

Comment: This error message came back: `Error: unexpected symbol in: "Testdf[, Benchmark := Value[which.min(Number[Measure == "Batch Time"])], by = group`

Comment: I am testing using this data.table: `DT <- data.table(Value = 1:10,Measure = c("Batch Time","Other"), Number = 1:5, group = letters[1:3])`, and then `DT[, Benchmark := Value[which.min(Number[Measure == "Batch Time"])], by = group]` works for me. Is the later code exactly what is being run though R?

Comment: The tables above are entirely example data sets. The real data is much more varied in terms of how many `Category` entries there might be per `FileName` and where a `FileName` might not have any entries for a particular `Number`.

Comment: @David Fair, but the error you are getting has nothing to do with the contents of your data.table. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889234/error-unexpected-symbol-input-string-constant-numeric-constant-special-in-my-co. Because I am not getting that error on my side, it is likely that there was an error transferring into your rscript

Comment: I tested it by removing everything but the code that calls the SQL table and the code you provided. Now when running it, the code doesn't appear to finish executing because the console goes from `>` to `+`

Comment: @David you missed the close bracket `]` on copy then

Comment: Haha, i did. Well at least it was a stoopid mistake

Comment: Okay so running that I get `Error in '[.data.frame'(Testdf, , ':='(Benchmark, Value[which.min(Number[Category==  : 
  unused argument (by = group)`

Comment: @David Testdf is not a data.table then. you need to used `library(data.table)` and then `setDT(Testdf)`.

Comment: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'group' not found`

Comment: What is group? That jumped out as strange because that wasn't found in the original data

Comment: sorry should be FileName

Comment: eureka! It works! :) I really appreciate it. Now I've got to figure out why my chart is still not working. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why `data.table` would cause a part of the data frame to print (unintentionally) on a PDF for a .Rnw file.

Comment: @David As we talked about before, this seems to be a new problem. Search on SO first, and then if you can't find ask a new question.

Comment: Just reading the code, it doesn't make sense to me. I think you should have `Value[Category == "Time"][which.min(Number[Category == "Time"])]` instead. Alternately, you could do `Value[which.min(Number*(Category == "Time"))]`, assuming the number is nonnegative.

Comment: @Frank when I use my test data.table, I get equivalent solutions. Is there a case where mine would break down? It is also the quickest of the three in a microbenchmark test

Comment: @Chris Suppose we have `V = 1:4; X = c(2,2,2,1); CatTime = c(T,F,T,T)` There is a difference between `V[which.min(X[CatTime])] # 3` & `V[CatTime][which.min(X[CatTime])] # 4`. I think the latter is the correct value, but I didn't read the question carefully (though I can't imagine a question for which the first version would be right). Oh, I was wrong about multiplying them being okay...I'm too used to taking the max.

Comment: @Frank my mistake. My method worked for a few test cases, and I (very incorrectly) thought that data.table would subset the way I wanted. Your method is the desired outcome, I've edited to reflect

Comment: @Chris I've noticed that there is a point where this breaks down. I have a File entry where there is no entries until `Number` gets to 13. This leads to `NA` values in the `Benchmark` column for that file.

Comment: @David did you use my fixed code above (current as of this morning)? The code should work for all possible values of number. Is the value in category for that row "Time"

Comment: @Chris I had a thought (that seems really obvious and stupid that I didn't mention it) that might be a source of breakdown in the codes usability. 

Will this code work when there are entries:

`Measure == 'Time' | Value == null | Number == 1`

`Measure == 'Time' | Value == 256| Number == 2`

Will the code choose `Value == 256` for the `Benchmark` column or will it try to use `null`?

Comment: should pull null. to fix this, use `[is.numeric(Value) & Category == "Time"]` instead of `[Category == "Time"]` in both locations above

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should get you started:

```
Ref <- Table1 %>%
  mutate(Category2 = factor(Category, c("Time", "Size", "Final"),
    FileNumber = as.numeric(sub("File", "", FileName)),
    FilePrefix = "File") %>%
  arrange(FilePrefix, FileNumber, Category2, Value) %>%
  group_by(FilePrefix, FileNumber, Category2) %>%
  mutate(NewColumn = Value[1])
```

Comment: It's your first table.  You didn't give it a name, so I named it Table 1.

Comment: okay that's what I assumed. I wanted to make sure. When you factor `Category` by listing the different category entries, will it make a difference if there are non equal distributions of Category names? 

For example, File1 might have `Time`, `Size`, `Final` where as File2 might have only `Time` and `Final` and File3 could have `Time`, `Size`, `Space`, `Final`.

Comment: I think that depends on if you want it to matter.  Any level that isn't named is going to be assigned missing.  When the data frame sorts, it will push the missing values to the end.  so if you don't care about retaining the value, then no, it doesn't matter.  If you want that information, then it's a problem.  A safer approach (that I should have mentioned initially) would be to do `mutate(Category2 = factor(Category......)`.  Then you still have the original data.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: When I run this, I get `Error: could not find function "%>%"`. I thought I had seen that used before but I can't find any documentation on what that operator is.

Comment: Also, when I look at the object `ref`, its only a dataframe with the FileName and NewColumn.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  use `library(dplyr)` to run this code.  Hopefully that takes care of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82861/discussion-between-david-and-benjamin).

Comment: Its still giving me a data frame with only two columns